# React scroll-snap flicker when using useState

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, flicker, scroll-snap

I am experiencing a very weird flickering (glitch) when using the combination of

- css scroll-snap
- useState
- Sub-Components

But ONLY in the combination of these three!

[image: flickering]

Here is the minimal reproducable code:

**carousel.js**

```
import styles from './carousel.module.scss'
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

export default function Carousel() {
  const [currentScollPos, setCurrentScrollPos] = useState(0)
  const carouselRef = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    const carouselScrollUpdate = (e) => {
      setCurrentScrollPos(e.target.scrollLeft)
    }
    carouselRef?.current?.addEventListener('scroll', carouselScrollUpdate, { passive: true })
    return () => {
      carouselRef?.current?.removeEventListener('scroll', carouselScrollUpdate, { passive: true })
    }
  }, [carouselRef])

  const Slide = () => <div className={styles.carouselSlide}>Test Sub</div>
  
  return (
    <div className={styles.carouselInnerContainer} ref={carouselRef}>
      <div className={styles.carouselSlide}>Test1</div>
      <div className={styles.carouselSlide}>Test2</div>
      <div className={styles.carouselSlide}>Test3</div>
      <Slide />
    </div>
  )
}
```

**carousel.module.scss**

```
.carouselInnerContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}

.carouselSlide {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  height: 200px;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
}
```

The flickering will **NOT** be there if I do ONE of the following:

- comment out: `setCurrentScrollPos(e.target.scrollLeft)`
- comment out: `<Slide />`
- comment out: `scroll-snap-align: center;` in the CSS

Any ideas on that weird behaviour?

Comment: Where do you use currentScollPos?

Comment: In the minimal reproducable example: nowhere. in reality: to calculate the nearest slide in view. But you could imagine something like: `useEffect(() =>{console.log(currentScollPos)},[currentScollPos])` if that helps. Unfortunately it does not make a difference whether it is used or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs when you try update the state every time the scroll position changes

```js
const carouselScrollUpdate = (e) => {
  setCurrentScrollPos(e.target.scrollLeft)
}
```

Each setCurrentScrollPos will cause a renderer in your component, causing it to flicker

Instead set state every time you can observer when the scroll stops using setTimout:

```js
const carouselScrollUpdate = (e) => {      
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('set scroll')
        setCurrentScrollPos(e.target.scrollLeft)
    }, 500);      
}
```

or just set your state when it satisfy some condition:

```js
const carouselScrollUpdate = (e) => {      
    if (isNearNextSlide()) {
      setCurrentScrollPos(e.target.scrollLeft)
    }         
}

const isNearNextSlide = () => {
   // add logic to satisfy your conditions
}
```

**Edit:**

After some testing I saw the problem is the inner Slide component inside  and I managed to fix it by moving the  component outside the main  component, preventing that the  component from being recreated when  rendering

```js
import styles from './carousel.module.scss'
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

const Slide = () => <div className={styles.carouselSlide}>Test Sub</div>

export default function Carousel() {
  const [currentScollPos, setCurrentScrollPos] = useState(0)
  const carouselRef = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    const carouselScrollUpdate = (e) => {
      setCurrentScrollPos(e.target.scrollLeft)
    }
    carouselRef?.current?.addEventListener('scroll', carouselScrollUpdate, { passive: true })
    return () => {
      carouselRef?.current?.removeEventListener('scroll', carouselScrollUpdate, { passive: true })
    }
  }, [carouselRef])
      
  return (
    <div className={styles.carouselInnerContainer} ref={carouselRef}>
      <div className={styles.carouselSlide}>Test1</div>
      <div className={styles.carouselSlide}>Test2</div>
      <div className={styles.carouselSlide}>Test3</div>
      <Slide />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am absolutely aware of the rerender. There is a ton of examples using useState to store the scroll-position (i.e. https://designcode.io/react-hooks-handbook-usescrollposition-hook). So it does not seem to be bad practice. AND: if I comment out  the sub-component <Slide /> everything works as expected. So the rerender-cycle of react **cannot** be the source of the proplem!
I like the setTimeout workaround anyway. So thank you!

Comment: By the way: I already tried the second idea (set state conditional): this causes the same proplem!

Comment: I tried your first idea (setTimeout). Really scary: it is still the exact same flickering but only in 500ms slow-motion. at the very same moment as "set scroll" is displayed in the console, the scroll-bar snaps back to the next scroll-snap-position and then flips back to the current mouse cursor. so it seems to be closely connected to the css scroll-snap-feature.

Comment: @somecoder Please check my last update in the answer